# Gradle multi-project conditional dependencry

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

How would one create an Android Studio (Gradle) multi-project configuration such that `projB` depends on `project(':projA')` if `projA` is defined, but uses a file in `libs/` otherwise?

Since it may be asked, in this case `projA` is an SDK; `projB` is a test application designed to demonstrate the SDK.  If the SDK team gets a bug report, it often includes reproduction steps using `projB`.

When `projB` team does work, they do so on RC builds of `projA`, whereas the SDK team uses `projB`, with a dependency on `project(':projA')` so that a debug session can be run.

`projB` has no specific definition of its dependency on `projA`; that team takes the `projA` output from the build server and drops it in the `libs/` folder, and has a wildcard dependency.

**EDIT**
I finally went with this code in the dependencies closure, and it works like a charm:

```
def sdkRef

project.getRootProject().allprojects.each { proj ->
    if (proj.name.equals("Sdk")) {
        sdkRef = proj;
        return true;
    }
}

if (sdkRef) {
    println "SDK present in project; using project reference as dependency"
    compile sdkRef
} else {
    println "SDK is not present in project; using libs/"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if that's something you can do with flavors and build variants.

Through code you might try in your build file :

```
dependencies {
 if (project.getRootProject().findProject(":projectA")) {
    compile project(":projectA")
  } else {
    compile files("libs/projectA.jar")
  }
}
```

One thing you have to consider is that your `settings.gradle` defines what modules are included in your project. So your two teams might end up with different files anyway for the project.

Comment: My only issue with this solution is it changes `projB`, where ideally that project's `build.gradle` wouldn't change and the dependency definition would be in some `settings.gradle` file, but it's good enough for now.

Comment: Wonder if you can create a build that drops the artifact generated by `projectA` into `projectB/libs`, so projectB only has the `lib/ProjectA` dependency.

An issue with this of course would be triggering that build before B starts to evaluate itself (without modifying B). You'd have to do it manually :\

Comment: Guess I couldn't get to your edit in time, either way, maybe using project.rootProject.findProject(":projectA") is better?

Comment: To address your comment about the `settings.gradle` file, I agree, but we have a checked in version that devs can use as reference.  I cant seem to find a solid way of doing this without some fragility.  Perhaps making a special project property would work, then I could key off that and non-unique project names wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with [*productFlavors*](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors).

You just have to define:

- 2 product flavors in `projB/build.gradle`
- a specific dependency for each flavor

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        demo{}
        sdkdev{}
    }
    ...
}

dependencies{
    demoCompile files("libs/projectA.jar")
    sdkdevCompile project(":projectA")
    ...
}
```

The build will produce 2 apks.

In Android studio, someone from the demo team can run the demo flavor by selecting the "demoDebug" (or "demoRelease") variant (in *Build Variant* tab) and someone from sdk team will select the "sdkdevDebug" variant.

The `gradle.settings` must contains references for projA and projB, but a user from demo team will never have to compile projA because the demo flavor have no dependencies on it.

Comment: The goal is to make this seamless in Android Studio, so that both the Devs and the demo project devs run their projects without intervention.  Having another flavor means communicating more to the team that they need to do something special.

Comment: ok... but with your current solution: you have to say to one of the team to modify the gradle.settings after checkout (+never commit it !!!). The solution that I suggest is IMO far less problematic: "the demo team have to use the demo build; the sdk team have to use the sdk build."

Comment: No, we check in the gradle scripts on both.  It's a one-time edit.

Comment: if your both teams are really sharing the same gradle.settings file, then `sdkRef` should be true for both team. So I guess you use different settings.gradle (or I'm missing something)

Comment: No, the SDK team loads a settings file that references both the demo app and the SDK to debug the SDK.  The demo team loads a different project with just the demo app, and references official builds.

Comment: Perhaps you can help with another question I have here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654583/android-gradle-fails-to-build-after-clean-depends-on-aar-with-native-libraries